# Getting user_likes approved when the process happens in the backend

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-permissions

I am trying to get the user_likes permission approved in my mobile app.
It gets rejected because the process is not visible in the app.
The Likes are processed in the back end, filtered for keywords and the likes themselves are never kept. The keywords are fully visible to the users.
Did anybody have this happen to them ? Did you post your code in the request for permissions page , or a flow chart of the back end process ?

Comment: what for do you use the likes? does the user benefit in any way from it?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in the question. Yes they would. But the benefit is experience 2 to 3 days later when the process is complete, not while using the app. I outlined this benefit in the request on Facebook developers console. But it cannot be shown in the video submitted.

Comment: ok, those things are usually hard to explain to the review team. i suggest joining this group and asking for help over there: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ - add your app id.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will ask for further help on the forum.